# How to retrieve encrypted data from database irrespective of case?

Tags: c#, sql, encryption

I want to retrieve encrypted data from the database Sql, irrespective of the case they were inserted in the database.I have the data in database in encrypted form but when i retrieve that data using different case it gives me 
wrong or no  data.

For Ex:

I have inserted `Abc` in the database the salt created for this value would be different for `abc`.

Now the user Wants to search for `aBc` these values are same but all have different salt.`Abc` has different encrypted value,`abc` has different in the database. How i can get the value irrespective of the salt created without problem of case sensitive.

I have no option available to check what was the case at the time of Insertion in database.

note: salt is created in the application using c#.

Is it possible,if not what is/are my options?

Should  I standardize my Field at the time of Insertion Like `ToUpper()` or `To Lower()`?

Comment: If you tag dbms used, you'll probably get better attention...

Comment: Yes, generally if you want case-insensitive search, you normalize data with tolower/toupper on insert. Though it's usually still possible to perform case-insensitive search using `where toupper(user_string) = toupper(column_value)`, even though this is generally inefficient. However, you're talking about encryption, so I'm not sure if that's possible. Show us some sample data and your query?